# How to safely shutdown SSL connection

Tags: ssl, go

Using Go, how can a tls.Conn be safely shutdown without entirely closing the underlying connection? I have a working solution, but I am not sure if there is a better way.

In my application I have a non-SSL connection that is eventually 'upgraded' to an SSL connection. Then at some point the SSL connection should be closed cleanly, and the connection should return to the non-SSL version (where unencrypted traffic can be sent between the two parties).

Something like this:

```
import "tls"
func app(connection net.Conn){
   // process some data on the connection, then eventually change it to SSL
   ssl = tls.Client(connection, sslConfig) // sslConfig defined elsewhere
   ssl.Handshake()
   // process data using ssl for a while
   // now shut down SSL but maintin the original connection
   ssl.CloseWrite()
   // at this point we have sent a closeNotify alert to the remote side and are expecting a closeNotify be sent back to us.
   // the only way to read the closeNotify is to attempt to read 1 byte
   b := make([]byte, 1)
   ssl.Read(b)
   // assuming the remote side shut down the connection properly, the SSL transport should be finished

   connection.Read(...) // can go back to the unencrypted connection
}
```

The part I dislike about this is having to make a 1 byte array and read from it just so that the SSL connection can read the notifyClose record.

Is there a better way to cleanly shutdown the SSL connection?

Comment: I've never heard of anybody trying this. Every implementation of STARTTLS I've ever seen leaves TLS active for the remainder of the connection, with no way to "turn it off".

Comment: So many questions...  Why not use TLS the whole time?  Why go back to it being off once you've turned it on?  How could that ever be a good idea?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: This is for example used in FTPS: It starts with `AUTH TLS` to upgrade to TLS and then after authentication might switch back to plain traffic with `CCC` so that any FTP helpers in firewalls can detect `PORT` commands or response to `PASV` in order to dynamically open necessary ports for data connection. See [RFC 4217](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4217#page-19).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich OK, now I've seen it, and almost wish I hadn't!

Comment: I am interfacing with a pre-existing application that I did not create. I agree the design is strange, but any critique about the design is moot.